# Is JTextField's inner vertical alignment broken with Java 11?

Tags: java, swing, java-11

after upgrading from Java 10 to Java 11 the text in a JTextField is not vertically centered anymore. Is there something I can do to get back the old behaviour? Following code run with JDK 10 (upper window in image) and JDK 11.0.8 for Windows (lower window in image) reproduces the problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class JTextFieldTest{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextField textInputField = new JTextField(20);
    textInputField.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    textInputField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 30));
    textInputField.setSize(textInputField.getPreferredSize());
    textInputField.setVisible(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(textInputField);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Output of code with JDK 10 and 11:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiNqQ.png]

Comment: I can also verify the vertical alignment is different than JDK8 on Windows 10. However, I don't know how to fix the difference.

Comment: I fixed it for the moment with textInputField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 0, 0, 0));
But that is quite a dirty hack of course...

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but agree is is a dirty hack. Is this a problem with all fonts? Maybe you can also check the FontMetrics on both versions to see if any properties might have changed from version to version.

Comment: I think the issue is with the font and not with the `JTextField`. Do you get the same behavior when you use the default font?

Comment: Take a look at [Calibri Font when in <html> text moves to the bottom part of the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565649/calibri-font-when-in-html-text-moves-to-the-bottom-part-of-the-component).

Comment: You are right, the font metrics changed for some fonts and especially for Calibry they changed a lot. There are already some bug reports about this, see e.g. here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215290 but it does not look like this is going to be fixed. So either I go with the dirty hack described earlier or I just switch to a font where the metrics have not changed so badly. Thanks all.