# Misaligned font with OpenJDK

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt

I'm experimenting with different fonts for a Swing UI and I've noticed a strange effect when switching from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 16. Using two versions of the Lato font (the version 1 available from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato), and the version 2 available from [latofonts.com](https://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/)), there is a significant difference in the position of the baseline with the version 2 on OpenJDK.

Here is an example with Oracle JDK 8:

[image: Font rendering with Oracle JDK 8]

And an example with OpenJDK 16:

[image: Font Rendering with OpenJDK 16]

On Oracle JDK 8 the baseline is the same for both fonts, but on OpenJDK 16 the Lato 2 baseline is higher. The text is no longer vertically centered relatively to the checkbox and to the text field.

I don't understand why this happens. Is this a bug in the JDK? Or an issue with the font file? I've opened both fonts in [FontForge](https://fontforge.org) and they look quite similar.

I'm aware the font rasterizer used by OpenJDK (FreeType) is different from the one in the Oracle JDK 8 (T2K). I also know that the Lato 2 font could be shifted by [deriving the font with an AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-) but that sounds like a dubious hack.

Comment: Perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565649/calibri-font-when-in-html-text-moves-to-the-bottom-part-of-the-component . Maybe not.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, there is indeed the same issue with the Calibri font. Looking at the font metrics, Lato 1 has a leading of 0 at all font sizes, and Lato 2 has a leading of 20% relatively to the size.

Comment: I still use to this day the accepted answer of my question. Maybe you could try something similar. And my other answer in the same question uses hacky reflection. I doubt if it will work in Java 16.

Comment: Likely related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8251836